# Adjust curvature of igraph mark.groups polygons when plotting networks in R

Tags: r, igraph

I was following the guide at https://kateto.net/network-visualization, and was wondering if there is a way to set the curvature of the polygons produced by the `mark.groups` option to zero, and so that their borders are straight lines (ideally they would still "loop around" the different sized nodes).

If possible, I would like the polygons to wrap exactly around each node (without any space inbetween), but if that is not possible, I can work with setting the size of the nodes to zero.

Any help is appreaciated. I can also work with other software if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the docs before, but found them now. The additional options are `mark.expand=0` and `mark.shape=0`: https://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.igraph.html